# How to get type of an argument of ctor inside a C# 9 code generator?

Tags: c#

I wrote a bunch of code as following

```cs
public class MockableGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    private const string AttributeText = @"
    namespace System
    {
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
        public sealed class MockableCodeGenAttribute : Attribute
        {
            public MockableCodeGenAttribute(Type type)
            {
                Type = type;
            }
            internal string Class { get; set; }
            internal string Namespace { get; set; }
            internal Type Type { get; set; }
        }
    }"
    ;

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        context.AddSource("MockableCodeGenAttribute", SourceText.From(AttributeText, Encoding.UTF8));

        if (!(context.SyntaxReceiver is SyntaxReceiver receiver))
            return;

        CSharpParseOptions options = (context.Compilation as CSharpCompilation).SyntaxTrees[0].Options as CSharpParseOptions;
        Compilation compilation = context.Compilation.AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(SourceText.From(AttributeText, Encoding.UTF8), options));

        INamedTypeSymbol attributeSymbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.MockableCodeGenAttribute");

        var namedTypeSymbols = new List<Tuple<INamedTypeSymbol, Info>>();
        
        foreach (var cls in receiver.CandidateClasses)
        {
            SemanticModel model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(cls.SyntaxTree);
            var clsSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(cls);
            var attr = clsSymbol.GetAttributes().FirstOrDefault(ad => ad.AttributeClass.Equals(attributeSymbol, SymbolEqualityComparer.Default));
            
            ...
```

Then use the generator like below

```cs
[MockableCodeGen(typeof(Dapper.DynamicParameters))]
public static class MySample { }
```

I want to access the type of `MockableCodeGenAttribute` ctor argument. I want to use reflection on `Dapper.DynamicParameters`.

How to access to `typeof(Dapper.DynamicParameters)` inside `Execute()` via `attributeSymbol` or `attribute` variables?

**Edit**

`attr?.ConstructorArguments[0].Value` is an `object?` and cast to `System.Type` does not work. I need the exact result of `typeof(Dapper.DynamicParameters)`.

Comment: You've got the `AttributeData`, so just look at `.ConstructorArguments`?

Comment: I can not get the actual type from there. It has some properties like Kind, Type, Value. How to get the actual result of typeof(Dapper.DynamicParameters)?

Comment: You're not going to get a `Type` object, because that's a runtime concept which isn't available at compile-time. The `.Value` will be a symbol representing the `typeof(...)` expression

Comment: attr?.ConstructorArguments[0].Value is an object? but I want the exact typeof(Dapper.DynamicParameters). I want to reflect on its assembly.

Comment: Look at the actual runtime type of `attr.ConstructorArguments[0].Value`

Comment: attr?.ConstructorArguments[0].Value is an object? and cast to Type does not work.

Comment: What is the runtime type? What type does the debugger show? What does .GetType() return?

Comment: I said earlier you're not going to get a `Type` object representing `typeof(Dapper.DynamicParameters)` in Roslyn. You should be able to get an `INamedTypeSymbol` though

Comment: Let me ask this. I want to access to the whole static method of the assembly has `DynamicParameters`. I do this with reflection via var classess = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Dapper.DynamicParameters)).GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsClass && x.IsPublic).ToList();
            foreach (var cls in classess)
            {
                var methods = cls.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Where(m => !m.IsSpecialName).ToList();
}
Is it possible to have this kind of info there? (Without Type)

Comment: Please answer the question I've asked you several times now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225034/discussion-between-canton7-and-hamedfathi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result was:

```
var type = (INamedTypeSymbol)attributeData.ConstructorArguments[0].Value;
```

Then to scan all types in the assembly which that type lives in, use a `SymbolVisitor` with

```
type.ContainingAssembly.GlobalNamespace
```